# C# Файлы, отображаемые в память

Tags: c#, memory

Будет ли работать данная технология при передачи данных из/в приложение C# windows и Ubuntu находящейся внутри Virtual Box

Comment: Разумеется, нет. Как вы вообще это представляете-то?

Comment: Как приложение C# Mono на Ubuntu. Вопрос в том будет ли общая память в таком случае...

Comment: Вообще не понял, о чем вопрос. В голове файлы с расширением .cs, которые загружаются в оперативную память на виртуальной машине, и к ним нужен доступ из основной машины.

Comment: Нет. На Windows запущено приложение C#. Оно должно передавать данные в приложение C# Mono на Ubuntu которая крутится внутри виртуальной машины.

Comment: Вы понимаете что такое "виртуальная машина"?

Comment: Будет, при условии, если вы сможете как-то добраться до нужного участка памяти и `windows`, `ubuntu` и `virtualbox` вам вообще это позволят сделать. Насколько я помню у приложения в виртуальной машине нет доступа к общей памяти и у нее свое виртуальное пространство, да и сама `ubuntu` ничего не должна знать о памяти за ее пределами. Поэтому мне кажется ответ нет, не будет.

Comment: В таком случае вам проще будет настроить доступ по IP